# Excel VBA Set Range/Cells after searching/find a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, graph, find

'I am making a graph. First I would like to search the keyword "A-test" in column "B" and then select 10 rows and 2 columns from where I find the word. I am having difficultly to select the range. Please, help how to use "Set" function in this case.
 Here is the Macro I am testing

```
'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Sub Macro3()    
Macro3 Macro    
    Dim Ws As Worksheet    
    Dim i  As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim M As Range
    EndRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Offset(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 1
    For k = 2 To EndRow
        If Cells(k, 2) Like "*A*" Then
            Set M = Range("C1:L1", ActiveCell(i, 2).Offset(2, 10)) 'Difficult
            'Range("B1").Select 'test
            'Range("C1:L1,B4:L5").Select 'test
        End If
        'Cells(k, 2) Like "*A*"
    Next
End Sub
'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Here is the data.

```
Date    choice  Sample#1    Sample#2    Sample#3    Sample#4    Sample#5    Sample#6    Sample#7    Sample#8    Sample#9    Sample#10
2018/07/12 00:06:58 A-test  105259  103495  105225  103923  104536  103196  105020  104316  105317  103021
2018/07/12 00:07:03 B-test  105260  103848  105225  103923  104535  103196  105020  104316  105316  103021
2018/07/12 00:07:47 A-test  103108  101758  102702  101784  102592  101688  103971  103345  104344  101513
2018/07/12 00:07:51 B-test  103109  101410  102701  101785  102592  101688  103970  103346  104344  101513
2018/07/12 00:15:48 B-test  103108  101409  102702  101785  102593  101688  103971  103345  104345  101513
2018/07/12 00:40:16 B-test  103108  101408  102701  101785  102592  101688  103971  103345  104344  101513
```

Comment: do you mean 10 Columns and 2 Rows from Cells A-Test ?

Comment: Yes, but the word "A-test" changes the cell location. In a graph,  I am trying to compare the data between "A-test" and "B-test" just below "A-test" but I get multiple "A-test".

Answer (score 1):

Quicker to use the `Find` method. This assumes the text only occurs once, but can be adapted if this is not the case.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to find out why you probably don't need to select anything.

You might want to swap the 10 and 2 in `Resize` - not sure what you want there.

```
Sub y()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(What:="A-test", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Resize(10, 2).Select '10 rows, 2 columns

End Sub
```

---

If you want to refer to the larger range, assign it to a range variable and then you can access its properties and methods directly without needing to use `Select`.

```
Sub y()

Dim r As Range, rBig As Range

Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(What:="A-test", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    Set rBig = r.Resize(10, 2)
End If

'then do stuff with the 10x2 range
'eg colour it red
rBig.Interior.Color = vbRed

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway that I can use "Set" or "Set Union" function to it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but have added some code - is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that. I made the mistake. above.

Comment: If I also want to select "Title = Range("C1:L1").Select
"  at the same time. How can I do that?      Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i  As Long
     Dim k As Long
Dim r As Range
    
    EndRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Offset(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 1

For k = 2 To EndRow
  
Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(What:="A-test", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Resize(2, 11).Select
 Range("C1:L1").Select

 Next
    
    
End Sub

Comment: I have a title "Sample#1    Sample#2    Sample#3    Sample#4    Sample#5    Sample#6    Sample#7    Sample#8    Sample#9    Sample#10" in the "Range("C1:L1").Select". I would like to select them at the same time when I resize the selection. Thank you.

Comment: `Union(rBig, Range("C1:L1")).Select`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another problem. It doesn't select next "A-test".  It may have a problem with "For" statement. Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
' Dim Ws As Worksheet
 Dim k As Long
Dim r As Range, rBig As Range
    EndRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Offset(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
For k = 2 To EndRow
 Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(What:="A-test", Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    Set rBig = r.Resize(2, 11)
End If
  Union(rBig, Range("C1:L1")).Select
 Next
End Sub